# Регулярное выражение: не учитывать строку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Доброго времени суток! Как составить регулярное выражение, чтобы не учитывать строку, если в ней есть слово слово?

Comment: Тест кейс приведите пожалуйста. И скажите, что вы подразумеваете под словом "строка"?

Comment: есть много-строчный текст, нужно не учитывать при поиске строку, если в ней есть слово слово.

Answer (score 1):

Читаете кажду строку в цикле в переменную, далее примеряете проверку на вхождения слова по регулярке (например используя preg_match), и отбрасыавете елси слово нашлось или сохраняете если слова нет.

Comment: Об этом я догадался; Думал, может можно регуляркой.